# FMOD how to load mp3 file with using mp3 file name as parameter in android

Tags: android, file, load, mp3, fmod

I've problem with loading mp3 file.
when I give char array or jstring parameter to android java native method,
c source file doesn't work.

maybe path parameter is not working correctly.
what's wrong with it?

please answer to my question.

main.c

---

void Java_com_chocolate_player_PlayerMain_cPlaySound(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, const char* path)
{
    FMOD_RESULT result = FMOD_OK;

```
result = FMOD_System_CreateSound(gSystem, path, FMOD_CREATECOMPRESSEDSAMPLE | FMOD_OPENMEMORY, 0, &gSound);
CHECK_RESULT(result);

__android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "path", path);

result = FMOD_System_PlaySound(gSystem, FMOD_CHANNEL_FREE, gSound, 0, &gChannel);
CHECK_RESULT(result);
```

}

android java source

---

in play method ...
        char[] fmodPath = songPath.replace("/mnt", "").toCharArray();
        cPlaySound(fmodPath);

native method ...
    public native void cPlaySound(char[] path);

Comment: songPath example is "sdcard/music/kara.mp3"

Answer (score 0):

Add READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to your projects manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and path must begin with "/" symbol:

```
/sdcard/myfile.mp3
```

Comment: I added permission. android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE but result is same;
and "/" added.

log is like next
08-19 23:41:37.449: I/path(19222): (�@

Comment: I'm sure there is problem in file name... Try to add your own native method which opens given file name using fopen() and check i/o error...

Comment: I've used "/sdcard/music/kara.mp3" in Android and also in C source(main.c) when I tried in C source, it worked but in Android it didn't work.

Comment: Can I meet you, Tutankhamen in mIRC? I might be crazy for this problem. huk huk...

Comment: Sorry, i'm not actually online now... As I said, try to make your own native function in android and check why you can't open the file using fopen() function and then check the result...

Comment: without making fopen in C? Do I have to make android method for fopen?

Comment: I made this function in C. and I've invoked this function in android.
// C //
void Java_com_chocolate_player_PlayerMain_cfopen(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, const char* path)
{
 __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "path", path);
}
  // android // char[] fmodPath = testPath.toCharArray();
  cfopen(fmodPath);

Comment: Yes, in your native function at first line "void Java_com_chocolate_player_PlayerMain_cPlaySound(JNIEnv env, jobject thiz, const char path)" just try to call fopen(path,"rb") and check the result.

Comment: Thanks for reply in detail. I've followed your instruction. but it seems same result. after fopen(path, "rb") what do I have to do?

Comment: how to print or see result of fopen()?